# Powershell: Login with Invoke-WebRequest to a website fails

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

im trying to Login to a website with Powershell. It always fails with 403 code.

```
$LoginUri = "https://xxxx.netstock.co/session/new"
$LoginResp = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $LoginUri -SessionVariable "Session"
$LoginBody = @{
    authenticity_token = $LoginResponse.InputFields[1].value
    login = "hereisthelogin"
    password = "hereisthepassword"
    submit = "Log in"
}

$LoginResp = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $LoginUri -WebSession $Session -Body $LoginBody -Method "POST"
```

Result: Invoke-WebRequest : Der Remoteserver hat einen Fehler zurückgegeben: (403) Unzulässig.

Does anyone have an idea why? Is there anything "non standard" on this website?

Comment: What is the value of `$LoginUri`? `$Uri` is never used.

Comment: Session `uri` (`session/new`) and login `uri` (`session`) are different for this site

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake. $Uri=$LoginUri. Have corrected it.

Comment: @filimonic what does it mean?

Comment: You should `POST` data to `.../session`, not to `.../session/new` @alex

Comment: @filimonic thank you very, very much. I didnt't thought about it and tried a lot without success. That was the easy solution that i didnt saw :) Have a nice weekend and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

sites do not look very favorably on automated account opening, so they may put some obstacles of their own, these return the 403 code, that is, it is not related to powershell, it will give the same error in any request, I guess I think it returns 403 due to the [cors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) system.

Comment: The URI in the question leads to a _login_ page, not one for creating a new account.

Comment: @mklement0 i didnt saw that. You are right, Problem is solved. Thank you very much for your help.